# MPI Domain Decomposition and Block Tridiagonal Matrix

Tags: matrix, fortran, mpi

I need some advice regarding how to build a block tri-diagonal matrix having decomposed a 2D domain with MPI.
Let me explain, I need to solve a heat diffusion like equation in 2D, and to do so I decomposed the domain in blocks with MPI using the virtual Cartesian topology.
The decomposed domain is reported
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y78j.png), where the numbers in the cells represent the cell coordinate in global indices.

When I discretize my equation with finite differences for example, I obtain a block tridiagonal matrix like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdpQr.png), where again the numbers in the matrix are the cell coordinate in the same global indices as before.

As solver I use MUMPS, which requires to input the spars matrix with three vectors for each process containing:

- Global Row indices
- Global Column indices
- Corresponding element entry (the problem coefficient)

In serial it is trivial on how to do this, and in MPI with 1D domain (which leads to a tridiagonal matrix) it is easy as well.
The problem is that I am not able to find a clear sequence of indices to be assigned with do loops on each process, since the position in the computational domain (first image) after the discretization leads to non contiguous elements in the matrix (second image).

I know that graph reordering is performed by libraries such as Parmetis, but from what I understood it does not preserve the original domain decomposition pattern since it reorders at matrix level.
I think this should be trivial to do since it is a very common problem, but I cannot see a clear way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of Victor, I reordered the global indexing of my matrix following a "local" column major ordering.
Now the physical domain is mapped as:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIHES.png)
where the 4 top left elements belong to the process with rank 0, the bottom left 4 elements to the process with rank 1 and so on..
I created a draft code to assemble the matrix on Matlab, before porting it on Fortran. I will leave it here if anyone has the same issue. The code can probably be simplified a lot.

```
clc 
clear
% Global number of rows and columns 
gRow = 4;
gCol = 4;
% Number of processor along rows and columns
rProc = 2;
cProc=2;
% END OF USER INPUTS
rLoc = gRow/rProc;
cLoc = gCol/cProc;

%Global Indexing following column major
M = zeros(gRow,gCol);
gidx = 1;
for l = 1:cProc
    for i=1:rProc
        for j=1:cLoc
            for k=1:rLoc
                M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j) = gidx;
                gidx = gidx+1;
            end
        end
    end
end
rowidx = []; % rows of non zero elements 
colidx=[]; % Columns of non zero elements
gidx = 1;
for l = 1:cProc
    for i=1:rProc
        for j=1:cLoc
            for k=1:rLoc
                if (i-1)*rLoc+k ~=1 && (i-1)*rLoc+k ~=gRow && (l-1)*cLoc+j~=1 && (l-1)*cLoc+j~=gCol
                    A =  [M((i-1)*rLoc+k-1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j+1)...
                        M((i-1)*rLoc+k+1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j-1)];
                    A = sort(A);

                elseif (i-1)*rLoc+k ==1 && (i-1)*rLoc+k ~=gRow && (l-1)*cLoc+j~=1 && (l-1)*cLoc+j~=gCol
                    A =  [ M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j+1)...
                        M((i-1)*rLoc+k+1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j-1)];
                    A = sort(A);
                elseif (i-1)*rLoc+k ~=1 && (i-1)*rLoc+k ==gRow && (l-1)*cLoc+j~=1 && (l-1)*cLoc+j~=gCol
                    A =  [M((i-1)*rLoc+k-1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j+1)...
                        M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j-1)];
                    A = sort(A);
                elseif (i-1)*rLoc+k ~=1 && (i-1)*rLoc+k ~=gRow && (l-1)*cLoc+j==1 && (l-1)*cLoc+j~=gCol
                    A =  [M((i-1)*rLoc+k-1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j+1)...
                        M((i-1)*rLoc+k+1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) ];
                    A = sort(A);
                elseif (i-1)*rLoc+k ~=1 && (i-1)*rLoc+k ~=gRow && (l-1)*cLoc+j~=1 && (l-1)*cLoc+j==gCol
                    A =  [M((i-1)*rLoc+k-1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j)...
                        M((i-1)*rLoc+k+1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j-1)];
                    A = sort(A);
                elseif (i-1)*rLoc+k ==1 && (l-1)*cLoc+j==1
                    A =  [ M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j+1)...
                        M((i-1)*rLoc+k+1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) ];
                    A = sort(A);
                elseif (i-1)*rLoc+k ==1 && (l-1)*cLoc+j==gCol
                    A =  [ M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j)...
                        M((i-1)*rLoc+k+1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j-1)];
                    A = sort(A);
                elseif (i-1)*rLoc+k ==gRow && (l-1)*cLoc+j==1
                    A =  [M((i-1)*rLoc+k-1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j+1)];
                    A = sort(A);
                elseif (i-1)*rLoc+k ==gRow && (l-1)*cLoc+j==gCol
                    A =  [M((i-1)*rLoc+k-1,(l-1)*cLoc+j) M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j)...
                        M((i-1)*rLoc+k,(l-1)*cLoc+j-1)];
                    A = sort(A);
                end
                colidx = cat(2,colidx, ones(1,length(A))*gidx);
                rowidx = cat(2,rowidx,A);
                gidx = gidx+1;
        
            end
        end
        %UNCOMMENT IF YOU WANT TO PLOT DATA OWNED BY EACH PROCESS
%         S = sparse(rowidx,colidx,ones(1,length(colidx)),gRow*gCol,gRow*gCol);
%         figure
%         spy(S)
%         rowidx = [];
%         colidx = [];
    end
end
        S = sparse(rowidx,colidx,ones(1,length(colidx)),gRow*gCol,gRow*gCol);
        figure
        spy(S)
```

The only inputs to be passed are the number of global rows and columns and the number of process along rows and columns. The code has been tested with different number of global rows and columns and different number of process along the two directions. It should be flexible.
However always check if this is working correctly.
By uncommenting the section near the end you can plot the elements owned by each process inside the matrix.

If the overall matrix is plotted it will look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eXLy.jpg) (without lines or textboxes)

Answer (score 0):

Your partitioned domain is based on the sequential ordering. Translating that to local ordering is kinda tricky. It would be easier if you first numbered all points on proc 0, then all points on proc 1, et cetera. That gives you a matrix with a slightly different structure, but the same solution and largely the same properties.

Comment: Thank you, just to be sure I understood correctly this means that for example Proc 0 has elements: 1 2 3 4, proc 1: 5 6 7 8 and so on?  Could you give me an example? I am not sure I am following since in that case what would be the advantage?

Comment: "The problem is that I am not able to find a clear sequence of indices to be assigned with do loops on each process" Now it is clear.